# Objective-C, NSThread detach vs. performSelectorInBackground

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, nsthread

What is the differences between these two?

```
 [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(method) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
 [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(method) withObject:nil];
```

I normally use the second method to spawn a new thread. 
But I was wondering if I call this twice like shown below in a method then what is going to happen? Also If I have a tabmenu and each menu spawns a thread then which one I should use?

```
 [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(method1) withObject:nil];
 [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(method2) withObject:nil];
```

Comment: They are essentially the same. Look at [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5148980/objective-c-performselectorinbackground-v-s-detachnewthreadselector/5149043#5149043) for reference.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Objective C - performSelectorInBackground V.S detachNewThreadSelector?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5148980/objective-c-performselectorinbackground-v-s-detachnewthreadselector)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between \[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:\] and -performSelectorInBackground](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2092526/difference-between-nsthread-detachnewthreadselector-and-performselectorinbac)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are identical.  Here is the what the [official documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/CreatingThreads/CreatingThreads.html) has to say on this topic:

> In
>   iOS and Mac OS X v10.5 and later, all
>   objects have the ability to spawn a
>   new thread and use it to execute one
>   of their methods. The
>   performSelectorInBackground:withObject:
>   method creates a new detached thread
>   and uses the specified method as the
>   entry point for the new thread. For
>   example, if you have some object
>   (represented by the variable myObj)
>   and that object has a method called
>   doSomething that you want to run in a
>   background thread, you could could use
>   the following code to do that:
>
> [myObj
>   performSelectorInBackground:@selector(doSomething)
>   withObject:nil];
>
> The effect of calling
>   this method is the same as if you
>   called the
>   detachNewThreadSelector:toTarget:withObject:
>   method of NSThread with the current
>   object, selector, and parameter object
>   as parameters. The new thread is
>   spawned immediately using the default
>   configuration and begins running.
>   Inside the selector, you must
>   configure the thread just as you would
>   any thread. For example, you would
>   need to set up an autorelease pool (if
>   you were not using garbage collection)
>   and configure the thread’s run loop if
>   you planned to use it. For information
>   on how to configure new threads, see
>   “Configuring Thread Attributes.”

As for what happens if you do:

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(method1) withObject:nil];
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(method2) withObject:nil];
```

...you will spawn two new threads, one of which starts executing at `method1` and one of which starts executing at `method2`.  The threads may execute concurrently (i.e. the second one will not wait for the first one to terminate before it starts executing).